# Incorrect Single Sign On Url - Cant Update

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365, single-sign-on

I'm having an issue. 
I've set up a third party SSO with my office365 account. The third party SSO authenticates with my on-premesis Active Directory. The only difference between using an ADFS on premesis SSO and this one is that this one is located "in the cloud"...but i digress.

Anyways, I ran DirSync and enabled password sync between office365 and my AD. This was successful and is currently working.

Then I "federated" the domain to get it to work with SSO.

I connected to my office365 subscription using windows Azure AD Powershell (connect msol). I then successfully federated the domain.

To create the settings, I used the powershell command, “Set-MsolDomainAuthentication” and added some parameters afterwards to set up the service.

Due to a typographical error on my part, I incorrectly set the  “IssuerUri" “LogOffUri" “PassiveLogOnUri”  incorrectly.

I went back into Azure AD powershell and attempted to correct these parameters using the "Set-MsolDomainAuthentication” command. However, they WILL NOT update to the new values! Powershell “accepts” the command, but I see no front-end change of these url’s.

Obviously, the issue is, when trying to sign into microsoft online, it redirects me to an incorrect url, so i cant "sign on" using SSO. I still have backend access via the admin credentials.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late,but thought of updating so that it will help someone else

To remove federation apply below command.

a. If the domain is federated with ADFS:

```
Set-MsolADFSContext -Computer your_ADFS_server_computer_name

Convert-MsolDomainToStandard -DomainName yourdomain.com -SkipUserConversion:$true -PasswordFile C:\userpasswords.txt

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -Authentication Managed -DomainName yourdomain.com
```

b.If the domain is federated with another IdP:

```
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -Authentication Managed -DomainName xxx.com (your domain)
```

Further reference

https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/203748160-Disabling-ADFS-federation-to-enable-OneLogin-SSO-with-Office-365

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the federation completely and reconfigure it. Look at the `Convert-MsolDomainToStandard` command.